# What to do to get notifications at regular interval of time?

Tags: android, wordpress, notifications

I don't know what query I should send through website admin so that our application get notification at regular interval of time.
I have developed application from the wordpress site.
Please help me guys what should i do to send notification to the app at regular interval of time. I have used firebase for notifications. I have got notifications if I sent it manually, but i want to sent notifications automatically whnever the news is updated on the website. basically i want to connect firebase with the website admin so that app users get notifications from the site at  regular interval of time.

Comment: question is too broad. But in general - do the request to google service to send notifications whenever you want notification to be sent.

Comment: where should i req

Comment: are you able to send a notification in general?

Comment: yup i can send notifications in general

Comment: If i sent notification in application through Firebase manually, then that notification i can get easily

Comment: ok, can you send notification using their API?

Comment: no i cant do this

Comment: so that is a first thing you should find out. See official documentation for that.

Comment: Official documentation for what?

Comment: for firebase push notifications API

Comment: data is fetched from the website

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: Please tell how can i do this ???

Comment: do you want me to copy-paste the documentation?

Comment: give me the link

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=firebase+notifications+api

Comment: I still didnt get it

Comment: ok, what makes a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the method periodically. The following method executes the assigned task after every five seconds.

```
  public void executePeriodicTask() {
        final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                             try {

                                //call the method that fetches your data here
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Interval test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                                    }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };


        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 50000 ms

    }
```

Comment: How to use it ?

Comment: just call `executePeriodicTask();` from your activities onCreate. You can replave this( `//call the method that fetches your data here`) comment with a toast just as i have edited, it will caall the Toast  after every five seconds. Now just replace the toast with the method you are using to request data from the server.

Comment: sorry but it didnt work for me

Comment: It has to work. unless you have asked your question incorrectly. Did you need assistance with making request in intervals or did you need assistance in writing the code to make the request?

Comment: I want to sent notifications automaticlly. that is possible only when firebse is connected with the website admin

Comment: you have to connect to a webservice in order for you to fetch information from there. The above code will only help you in making the request after a set amount of time. Just call your data fetcher in place of the toast in the above code.

Comment: I have solved that issue myself. thank you so much :)